# Is it possible to change the version of android running on BlueStacks?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, emulation, bluestacks

I am currently looking to test an application on Bluestacks but need it to run a specific API in order to debug a problem that is coming up.

The issue only seems to manifest itself with API 15 and trying to run a emulator within Android Studio using Android 4.0.3 has been fruitless due to it simply being stuck on a black screen and not making it to the Android logo loading screen.

So is it possible to change the version of Android that is running on BlueStacks to an earlier version? With using a terminal app I can see the current version running is 4.4.2 - API 19

Comment: use ghananation for is type of work

Comment: Was that meant to be Genymotion but autocorrected?

Comment: *due to it simply being stuck on a black screen*. @Mr.Espresso how much RAM do you have?

Comment: 4GB - MacBook Pro. The problem seems to be with the native emulator in Android Studio when running API 15, I have hardware/emulators to test the app on for APIs 16 and over but the bug seems to be with devices running API 15.